# Where to use 'GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float'?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Nowadays, iOS support an extension named 'GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float', and it can let the half float format accepted by the  parameter of glRenderbufferStorage.

But, in iOS, renderbuffer should be connected to CAEAGLLayer of the view like this:

```
- (BOOL) renderbufferStorage:(NSUInteger)target fromDrawable:(id)drawable
```

and only one renderbuffer can be created for one framebuffer. So, I think I should create another framebuffer to attach a new renderbuffer, and specify the internal format of it for 'half float'. Am I right?

Another question, there is another extension 'OES_texture_half_float' can be used by glTexImage2D, and we already can create half float texture attached to framebuffer directly. It seems that we have no need to render a half float renderbuffer attached to framebuffer. so what is the use scenario of 'GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renderbuffers do not have to be connected to a CALayer. There are many times where you need to do offscreen rendering of some sort, and having a half-float output type can be useful in some of those cases.

Apple showed one such example in the WWDC 2011 OpenGL ES sessions, where they presented deferred lighting working on an iPad 2. Kearwood Gilbert describes this technique in [a blog post here](http://kearwood.com/content/ios-development-deferred-lighting), although with only the standard 8-bit-per-channel color depth. Simon Yeung shows how to do this with half-float targets in [his article here](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/03/01/light-pre-pass-renderer-on-iphone/).

Personally, I've used it for image processing applications in machine vision. For example, I was recently working on a Hough transform line detector ([based on the work of Dubská, et al.](http://medusa.fit.vutbr.cz/public/data/papers/2011-SCCG-Dubska-Real-Time-Line-Detection-Using-PC-and-OpenGL.pdf)) where one of the steps required the detection of local maxima in a parallel coordinate space. Using the standard additive blending to accumulate the Hough transform votes was saturating the 8-bit color channels of my RGBA colorspace, but a half float would give me a lot more dynamic range to pick out true local maxima. Using this greatly reduces the noise in this process (although iOS 6's new framebuffer read operations may let me use a custom blend to encode higher-dynamic-range values in the four color channels).

Rendering to a half-float output does have some performance consequences, but it may be the only practical way to achieve certain effects.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I still feel puzzled that when Apple introduced this extension in WWDC 2011, they said it could be used in implementing a HDR effect. But in my opinion, if you want to do a HDR effect, you must use the fragment shader to calculate the tonemapping, so you also must use a texture attached from an offscreen framebuffer. No render buffer is needed in this process. Am I right?